# Why I am a getting 'int' object is not iterable error?

Tags: python, python-2.7

Instructions:

Write a function named roll_big that receives 1 numeric parameter. It generates random numbers from 1 to the size of the parameter; adding the numbers together. It stops when a 1 is rolled. The 1 is not counted, but the sum of the rest of the numbers is returned.

I don't understand why the for loop is having problems with my code. What do I need to fix?

```
import random
def roll_big(x):
    count = 0
    while True:
        for i in random.randrange(1,x):
            if i == 1:
                return count
            else:
                count += i
```

Comment: What does the documentation for randrange tell you?

Answer (score 3):

`randrange` does not return a sequence, it simply returns a number:

```
import random

def roll_big(x):
    count = 0
    while True:
        i = random.randrange(1, x)
        if i == 1:
            return count
        else:
            count += i
```

[Documentation for randrange.](http://docs.python.org/2/library/random.html#random.randrange)

Answer (score 0):

`random.randrange(1,x)` returns a single integer between 1 and x, not a list. You need to amend your code to something like the following (note: untested):

```
def roll_big(x):
    count = 0
    while True:
        i = random.randrange(1, x)
        if i == 1:
            return count
        else:
            count += i
```